# Getting Undefined from Signing out using rnfirebase :

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

When I try to signout from rnfirebase I get an undefined error, here's what my code looks like :

CompileSdk = 33
Android = 11
Latest version of rnfirebase

```js
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export default function App() {
const SignOut = () => {
  auth.signOut().then(() => console.log('User Signed Out')).catch(e => console.log(e.message));
}

return(
  <>
    <Button onPress={SignOut}>Sign Out</Button>
  </>
)
}
```

I tried Async Await but I got an unhandled Promise, I reinstalled it serveral of times but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer found :

I forgot that the auth import is not an object, It's a function so the fix is :

```js
const SignOut = () => {
  auth().signOut().then(() => console.log('User Signed Out')).catch(e => console.log(e.message));
}
```